# Why is firebase failing to create a new user?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make it so that the user can enter in various importation and that firebase can enter this information into the Runtime DB. However, when I press the button that makes the code below happen, it results in the progress bar loading forever. I tried throwing in the log to try to catch some exception, but no exceptions came up. On the firebase console, the user was not created in the authentication and nothing was added to the RunTime DB. I am not sure what is causing this to happen, and I would appreciate any and all help.

Code:

```
    User user = new User(fullName, email, bio, username,location,realstatus,profilePic);

    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference root = db.getReference().child("Users");

    progressBar.setVisibility(ViewStub.VISIBLE);
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Create User Succeeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to Authenticate :( ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
            root.push().setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(ViewStub.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to Register User :( ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("Create user", "Failed to create user", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Error:

```
com.google.firebase.FireBaseException:
An internal error has occured. [ socket failed EPERM:(Operation not permitted) ]
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a complete listener to the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() operation, to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: No I have not tried that yet. Will try it now

Comment: Updated The Post.

Comment: So does `Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to Authenticate :( ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` display some message?

Comment: It just displays the text "Failed to Authenticate" if the createUser operation failed but I'm not getting an exception or anything with more nuance unfortunately.

Comment: You aren't getting an Exception because you don't display it. Try to display `task.getException().getMessage()`. What do you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230879/discussion-between-john-green-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Change `else{ Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to Authenticate :( ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }` to `else{ Log.e("Auth", "Failed to authenticate", task.getException()); }` and include the full error message and stack trace from the logcat output in your question.

Comment: Hmm. I added the log statement but when I run the code, nothing pops up in logcat, the build or in the app itself which is strange.

Comment: I used Toast to show the error instead and I've added it the post

Comment: I looked into the error that showed up and I was able to fix it by adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to my Android XML file. Thank alll you for your help!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. When dealing with tasks, always check if they succeeded. If it succeeded you can get `task.getResult()`. If it failed, always log `task.getException()` to find the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a completion listener to the createUser so you can know why it isn't working.

```
           mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, task -> {
                    binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //get the error here with task.toString();

                    } else {
                        save your database data here
                    }
                });
```

That will at least help you get to the bottom of why it is failing. Also make sure you have

1. enabled email auth in firebase console
2. Have properly set up your app, the SHA-1s, the google-services json and all

Comment: Email is enabled in the console and I believe everything else is setup. I'll try to add the listener and see what it says

Comment: Updated The Post.

Comment: Adding the completion listener was so that it tells you why it is failing. So why is it failing?

Comment: I'm not sure.. I don't see any exceptions or anything useful in logcat.